# Why calling thunk is specific from app.tsx?

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-thunk

When I call `me` thunk from app.tsx, it returns this error:

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null
    at exports.useContext (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at useReduxContext (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useReduxContext.js:27:46)
```

Why app.tsx is specific to all other component?

```js
import { useAppDispatch } from '../hooks'
import { me } from '../tikexModule/slices/tikexAPI'
const MyApp: Page = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) => {
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(me())
    }, [])

    return <></>
}

export default MyApp
```

And the thunk itself:

```js
export const me = createAsyncThunk(`${namespace}/me`, async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'me',
        headers: { crossDomain: true },
    })
    return data
})
```

and the action:

```js
const tikexAPI = createSlice({
    name: 'tikexAPI',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.authnRes = payload
            })
```

and hooks.ts

```js
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
    authnResS,
    userDTOS,
    organizationsS,
    selectedOrganizationIdS,
    selectedOrganizationS,
    selectedEventIdS,
    selectedEventS,
} from './tikexModule/slices/tikexAPI'
import {
    AuthnRes,
    OrganizationDTO,
    OrganizationList,
    SoldTicketRes,
    UserDTO,
    ProgramDTO,
} from './tikexModule/Types'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
```

Comment: That looks like a problem with your project setup, not like a problem with any or your code. What did you use to create this project? createReactApp?

Comment: Next.js I uses.

Comment: You're calling `useAppDispatch` inside `_app` but that component isn't getting wrapped by the Redux provider because it sits at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is in `dispatch`, where you dispatch a function **call** of the thunk, instead of **passing the thunk function** itself.

```
const thunkFunction = (dispatch, getState) => {
  // logic here that can dispatch actions or read state
}

store.dispatch(thunkFunction)
```

Note that `thunkFunction` has no parenthesis `()` to invoke the thunk.

In your case `me()` should be without parenthesis:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(me)
  }, [])
```

I don't work with thunks normally but I believe the reason that works is that a thunk has a toString() function that exposes the action type `` `${namespace}/me` ``.

Comment: I got same error without `()`

Comment: Could you nest the call to dispatch in a component that's mounted in App.tsx? Perhaps it's just because App.tsx (which extends Page) is the root level, which means redux hasn't initialised. Other than calling something in the root element I don't see anything strange.